# How to send byte array from Web api to android cliend using Retrofit

Tags: c#, android, arrays, asp.net-web-api2, retrofit2

I am trying to get a model from web api to android client using retrofit. One of the properties of that model is byte array which is not parsing. The whole model return null if I include that property else it returns model with appropriate data.

I have already tried this solution 
[How to send byte[] array in retrofit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31325723/how-to-send-byte-array-in-retrofit) where they are showing how to send byte array from client to server, but what i need is exactly opposite.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [helper](https://gist.github.com/orip/3635246) class to serialize bytes

```
public class GsonHelper {
    public static final Gson customGson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(byte[].class,
            new ByteArrayToBase64TypeAdapter()).create();

    // Using Android's base64 libraries. This can be replaced with any base64 library.
    private static class ByteArrayToBase64TypeAdapter implements JsonSerializer<byte[]>, JsonDeserializer<byte[]> {
        public byte[] deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
            return Base64.decode(json.getAsString(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
        }

        public JsonElement serialize(byte[] src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
            return new JsonPrimitive(Base64.encodeToString(src, Base64.NO_WRAP));
        }
    }
}
```

Credits to : [Orip](https://gist.github.com/orip)