# Using Kotlin, Convert existing PUT request into Retrofit 2

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I have existing web-service call, I need to convert it into Retrofit type.

below is existing web-service call function

```
public static RestRequest sharePassword(RestClient client, JSONObject passwordShare)
    {
        UriBuilder builder = client.getUriBuilder();

        try {
            return builder.appendPath("users").appendPath("me").appendPath("password-shares")
                    .build(RestMethod.PUT, new ByteArrayEntity(passwordShare.toJSONString().getBytes("UTF-8")));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I have written it into Retrofit form using Kotlin like below

```
@PUT("/users/me/password-shares/")
fun sharePassword(@Body entry : ByteArray)
```

can anyone suggest me, is this right? or do I need to do any change?, thanks.

Comment: Have you done connection of retrofit ?

Comment: No, because not sure that should I need to pass byte array as Body?

Comment: this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/31327334/10182897