# upload audio file with binary body with retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I need to upload audio file with binary body with retrofit like the image bellow in postman:

[image]

how can i upload audio file with binary body like the image with retrofit?

This is what I did but its not work:

```
@Multipart
@POST("upload")
fun uploadAudio(
    @Part audio_file: MultipartBody.Part
): Call<ModelGetAudioUrl>
```

And this is how I prepare audio file for multipartbody.Part:

[image]

Comment: Use an `@Body`-annotated parameter along with a suitable `RequestBody`, such as [the `InputStreamRequestBody` that I describe here](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/07/05/multipart-upload-okttp-uri.html).

Comment: @CommonsWare I read the link that you give it to me, but I couldn't understand what should I do to upload my audio file with binary body. Could you guide me what should I do? Thank you

Comment: He does not want to do Multipart, at least his screenshot shows something different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it by using okhttp:

```
val client = OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
        .callTimeout(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .connectTimeout(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build();
    val mediaType = "audio/wave".toMediaTypeOrNull();
    val body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, soundFile)
    val request = Request.Builder()
        .url("https://api.assemblyai.com/v2/upload")
        .method("POST", body)
        .addHeader("authorization", "99fa2a59e27e4688b9f7edcdc8ed7185")
        .addHeader("Transfer-Encoding", "chunked")
        .addHeader("Content-Type", "audio/wave")
        .build()

    Thread {

        try {


            val response = client.newCall(request).execute().use {

                if (it.isSuccessful) {

                    val str = it.body?.string()

                    if (!str.isNullOrEmpty()) {

                        val json = JSONObject(str)

                        sendUrlToTranscript(json.getString("upload_url"))

                    }

                }

                context.runOnUiThread {

                    if (!it.isSuccessful) {

                        loading.hideDialog()

                    }

                }

            }

        }catch (e: Exception) {

            e.printStackTrace()
            Log.d("uploadAudio", "uploadAudio: ${e.message}")

        }


    }.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your screenshot, you propably don't want to use a multipart body. So something like

```
@POST("upload")
fun uploadAudio(@Body audio_file: TypedInput): Call<ModelGetAudioUrl>
```

or `@Body audio_file: RequestBody` should work (see [How to send byte[] array in retrofit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31325723/how-to-send-byte-array-in-retrofit)).

Comment: Unfortunately its not worked. Did I prepare the audio file correctly for uploading?

Comment: You didn't share your file preparation nor your httpclient configm, I just guessed that you have a byte array already.